# How to get optional output in golang sqlc

Tags: go, sqlc

I have table which has column with name `next_timestamp`. And I want next incoming timestamp.
For this I wrote below query

```sql
-- name: GetNextTimestamp :one
SELECT MIN(next_timestamp) FROM tableA
WHERE next_timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

When it generated function, it looked like below

```golang
func (q *Queries) GetNextTimestamp (ctx context.Context) (interface{}, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, getNextTimestamp )
    var min interface{}
    err := row.Scan(&min)
    return min, err
}
```

It is returning `interface{}`, I was expecting `sql.NullTime`

I thought changing a sql query like below. but sometime `next_timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` this condition may not satisfy for any row which giving error `sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "min": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *time.Time`

```sql
SELECT MIN(next_timestamp)::timestamptz FROM tableA
WHERE next_timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am generating `.sql.go` files, so it is not a good thing to change them manually, right?

Comment: What does (the relevant part of) your schema look like?

Comment: Ah, this appears to be [an open issue](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/issues/1574)